# Filtering specific value from csv file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

I am having problem with filtering a specific value from my csv file. The csv file looks as follows:

```
"1","19/Oct/2016","15:03:58","19/Oct/2014","15:03:58","0:00:00","---","---","nice_meme@help.com","---","sip","1232Kbps","---","Out","1140","1","---","---","---","user:---","---","---","---","---","---","---","---","Failed Attempt; ""Your call could not be completedOver.""","3","---","---","---","---","---","---","---","---","---","---","---","---","---"
```

As you can see there are multiple values with '---', I tried a lot of ways to remove these three dashes. I do not know how to filter them out using PowerShell. I want to get the rows that are not equal to the three dashes.

Something like this:

```
$a = Import-CSV -Path "C:\Transformed\test.csv" | Where-Object {$_.Header -neq "---"}
```

Comment: From what i can see of your sample there is no .header Can you please provide a full sample of your CSV file?

Comment: "_rows that are not equal to the three dashes_" -- your CSV only has a single row?